# skip strtok's null terminators safely

Tags: c, string, strtok, ansi-c, null-terminated

I want to use `strtok` and then return the string **after** the null terminator that `strtok` has placed.

```c
char *foo(char *bar)
{
strtok(bar, " ");
return after_strtok_null(bar);
}
/*
examples:
foo("hello world") = "world"
foo("remove only the first") = "only the first"
*/
```

my code **is not** for skipping the first word (as I know a simple `while` loop will do) but I do want to use `strtok` once and then return  the part that was not tokenized.

*I will provide details of what I am trying to do at the end of the question, although I don't think it's really necessary*

one solution that came into my mind was to simply skip all the null terminators until I reach a non - null:

```c
char *foo(char *bar)
{
bar = strtok(bar, " ");
while(!(*(bar++)));
return bar;
}
```

This works fine for the examples shown above, but when it comes to using it on single words - I may misidentify the string's null terminator to be `strtok`'s null terminator, and then I may access non - allocated memory.

For example, if I will try `foo("demo"\* '\0' *\)` the of `strtok` will be `"demo"\* '\0' *\`
and then, if I would run the `while` loop I will accuse the part after the string `demo`. another solution I have tried is to use `strlen`, but this one have the exact same problem.

I am trying to create a function that gets a sentence. some of the sentences have have their first word terminated with colons, although not necessarily. The function need to take the first word if it is terminated with colons and insert it (without the colons) into some global table. Then return the sentence without the first colons - terminated word and without the spaces that follow the word if the word has colons - terminated word at the start and otherwise, just return the sentence without the spaces in the start of the sentence.

Comment: You could try `strtok(bar, " "); return strtok(NULL, "");`

Comment: @WeatherVane but then it will return the second word rather then the whole sentence

Comment: Look at the second 'separator' string I used.

Comment: @WeatherVane great way to do it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C language: How to get the remaining string after using strtok() once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724450/c-language-how-to-get-the-remaining-string-after-using-strtok-once)

Comment: When passed a single word, my code returns `NULL` rather than the empty string, but you could adjust for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str[c]spn` instead:

```
char *foo(char *bar) {
    size_t pos = strcspn(bar, " ");
    pos = strspn((bar += pos), "");
    // *bar = '\0';   // uncomment to mimic strtok
    return bar + pos;
}
```

You will get the expected substring of an empty string.

A good point is that you can avoid changing the original string - even if mimicing `strtok` is trivial...